# How to look at multiple conditions with a LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq

I'm currently using a linq statement to move items from one list to another based of a condition, but i need to add a second condition and i think i'm having a syntax issue

What I'm currently doing:

```
var selected = Generatorlist.CallDataGeneratorsDone
  .Where(item => item.SkillNumber == SkillNumber)
  .ToList();

Generatorlist.CallDataGeneratorsDone = Generatorlist.CallDataGeneratorsDone
  .Except(selected)
  .ToList();

Generatorlist.CallDataGeneratorsNotDone.AddRange(selected);
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
var selected = Generatorlist.CallDataGeneratorsDone
  .Where((item => item.SkillNumber) & (item => item.CallServer))
  .ToList();

Generatorlist.CallDataGeneratorsDone = Generatorlist.CallDataGeneratorsDone
  .Except(selected)
  .ToList();

Generatorlist.CallDataGeneratorsNotDone.AddRange(selected);
```

I'm having an issue because you can't us & in a Lambda expression. I'm looking for some assistance in figuring out a way to accomplish this.

Comment: What's the predicate for `item.CallServer`, what must it match?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the second declaration of `item =>` (it only needs to be defined once):

```
var selected = Generatorlist.CallDataGeneratorsDone
    .Where(item => item.SkillNumber && item.CallServer)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain Where calls together like so...

```
var selected = Generatorlist.CallDataGeneratorsDone
                .Where(item => item.SkillNumber)
                .Where(item => item.CallServer)
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I don't miss something, it should be `&&` instead of `&` in the same expression like this:

```
var selected = Generatorlist.CallDataGeneratorsDone
                .Where(item => item.SkillNumber && item.CallServer)
                .ToList();
```

This is assuming that both `SkillNumber` and `item.CallServer` are of Boolean. Otherwise you will need to write acomplete predicate like `item.SkillNumber = 'blah blah'`.

Comment: so this has to be boolean? Both of my variables are ints... Is there a way to do this with int? I can't do a ="blah blah" because there are multiple instances of this and it needs to pull the skill number and call server from each instance...if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

The solution in your case would be:

```
    Generatorlist.CallDataGeneratorsNotDone
                 .AddRange(Generatorlist.CallDataGeneratorsDone
                      .Except(Generatorlist.CallDataGeneratorsDone
                          .Where(item => item.SkillNumber && item.CallServer))
                          .ToList())
```